# combine array elements with elements of same array

Tags: java, arrays

What i'm trying to achieve is that, I have an array,

```
for eg: a={1,2,3}
```

Now, I need an array which combines all the elements in the array.

ie, the output that is needed should be like.

```
{[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]}
```

I know that,  in StackOverflow asking a question without showing what I have done is not at all appreciated, but still, I'm totally blank and i dont have any ideas to code this. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think it's to make a double loop. Like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
   {
      System.out.println("[" + array[i] + "," + array[j] + "]");
   }
}
```

Comment: In general, best to reply to these kinds of questions with *teaching* rather than a code dump

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I usually don't post code for this kind of questions but, in this case, it would be equals to put "You have to use 2 loops" that to put the code above. Anyway, thanks for alert to me ;)

Answer (score 2):

To generate the resulting array, use two loops, one nested inside the other, both using indexes (say, `i` and `j`) going from `0` through `< length` on the array. The two values for the resulting element in the new array come from `a[i]` and `a[j]`.